# CakePHP - Trying to Build Multiple SQL Inserts Using Model SaveMany( )

Tags: cakephp

I'm using cakephp 2.3.0. I have a scenario where I need to insert data in a table, but I need to do multiple inserts, based on the number of users that need the inserted data. If I have one value in the `$userIds array`, or more than 1 value in the `$userIds array`, then only one row is inserted in the table. i.e. if I had two values in the array, I would expect two rows to be inserted in my table.

I can't figure out how to correctly build my $message array with the different values from the `$userIds array`. In the example output below, the value of 5 gets overwritten by 3, and 3 gets overwritten by the value of 4.

When I have 2 or more values in the $userIds array, I confirm that the for loop is correctly looping through each time in the array, by the debug statement.

Below is the output of debug statements:

> \app\Controller\ActivitiesController.php (line 134)
>
> '5'
>
> \app\Controller\ActivitiesController.php (line 134)
>
> '3'
>
> \app\Controller\ActivitiesController.php (line 134)
>
> '4'
>
> \app\Controller\ActivitiesController.php (line 136)

```
array(
'Message' => array(
    'message' => 'The activity has been deleted.',
    'user_id' => '4'
    )
)
```

Below is my code snippet from my controller:

```
$this->Activity->Message->create();
                
foreach ($userIds as $ids) {
    $message = array(
        'Message' => array(
            'message' => 'The activity has been deleted.',
            'user_id' => $ids                                       
        )
    );
                    
    debug($ids);                        
}
debug($message);
$this->Activity->Message->saveMany($message);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reset your array each time instead of adding one element to it. So try changing your foreach like this

```
$message = array();
foreach ($userIds as $ids) {
    $message[] = array(
                    'Message' => array(
                        'message' => 'The activity has been deleted.',
                        'user_id' => $ids                                       
                    )
                );

    debug($ids);                        
}
```

Comment: Great, so that's how to do that. My code works just fine with that simple change. Thanks EmeraldCoder!